# Distinct users while using join statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a huge database 'Job seeker' having multiple table like username, skills, qualification, job, social media, etc. One user can have multiple columns on job, social media, etc. table.
Now if I use simple inner join I get multiple columns for single user.

```
Select user.user_id, user.name, s.skill_name, s.type , q.qualification, j.job_name, s_url
from username user
inner join skills s on s.skill_user = user.user_id
inner join qualification q on q.qualification_user = user.user_id
inner join job j on j.job_user = user.user_id
```

But what if I want top 1 row for each user. How can I do it?

Edit: Is there some other way to do this instead of using distinct?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: How do you define 'top'?

Comment: Not necessarily top, just one row for one user.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `distinct on ()`

```
Select distinct on (user.user_id) user.user_id, user.name, s.skill_name, s.type , q.qualification, j.job_name, s_url
from username "user"
  join skills s on s.skill_user = user.user_id
  join qualification q on q.qualification_user = user.user_id
  join job j on j.job_user = user.user_id
order by user.user_id;
```

This picks a "random" row from the result.

A more complicated way (but possibly more efficient) would be to pick only one row for each of the joined tables:

```
select distinct on (user.user_id) user.user_id, user.name, s.skill_name, s.type , q.qualification, j.job_name, s_url
from username "user"
  join lateral ( 
     select * 
     from skills s 
     where s.skill_user = user.user_id -- only for the "outer" user
     limit 1 -- only one skill for that user
  ) as s on true
  ... follow the same pattern for the other tables ...
```

The `on true` is necessary because a `join` needs a join condition but as we limit the rows for the current user in the derived table, there is no need to repeat that condition in the join condition.

Comment: Thank you so much I was trying the distinct() but was getting very frustrated and confused due to small errors. I used the first query and now it is working perfectly.